# How to Add script codes before the </body> tag ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, javascript, google-analytics

Heres the problem,

In Masterpage, the google analytics code were pasted before the end of  `body`  tag.

In ASPX page, I need to generate a script (google addItem tracker) using codebehind `ClientScript` and put it before the end of `body` tag, because this script uses the google analytics variables.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An inelegant but simple approach, if you're able to avoid using `ClientScript`, would be to just stick a literal in the page where you want your script to be rendered and put the script in there from your codebehind (i.e. `myLiteral.Text = "client script";`).

Comment: I was gonna post this, but I realized it would have to be in the master page, and therefore not accessible from his detail page via the normal means.

Comment: Good point Joel, I missed the bit about the master page. Sticking with the "inelegant-but-simple" theme, you could still get the literal with a good old Page.Master.FindControl("myLiteral") though.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy.aspx)

The script block will be placed right above the `</form>` tag at the end of the page.

Comment: This is what I use - it's good for custom controls etc. where you need a script to be executed last.

Comment: what if you need something to be after the </form> right before </body>?

Answer (score 0):

You could delay your script execution until after the page loads, then it won't matter where your script resides.